# What's the name for taking pictures of air flow in a normal room?

Tags: optics, air

There is a way to photograph air in a room. It makes convection, breathing and movement visible. The result looks a bit like a soap bubble.

This is some kind of optical effect. No special gases or fogs or powders are used.

What's this special form of photography called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You think of Schlieren method? 
Google for Schlieren or Schlieren-photography.

[EDIT]: Wikipedia article [Schlieren photography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlieren_photography)